# Why is presentModalViewController hindering UITextField responses?

Tags: objective-c, uikit, uitextfield, uikeyboard

Any uitextfield I add to a view which is presented from another view controller with `presentModalViewController:animated:` does not respond to any touch events (like the keyboard doesnt display when the uitextfield is tapped) also if i use `[textField becomeFirstResponder]` to force the keyboard to display, the only time this works is in the `viewDidLoad` method of the view controller

Anyone know why the uitextfield is not responsive whatsoever when i use `presentModalViewController:animated:` to display the view controller which the uitextfield is on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after much trouble i came to find that

```
-(BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {    
    return YES; 
}
```

was hidden in my code somewhere, this for some reason was not allow the textfield to become first responder if i added the view via the `presentModalViewController:animated:` method

Comment: Did you find a solution?  Are you saying that "return YES" was *NOT* allowing it to become firstResponder?   (I would think it *WOULD* allow it.)

Comment: yes well i didnt try return NO i just deleted it all and it all worked fine, you do know it was in the class that was presenting modalviewcontroller from not the modalviewcontroller itself

Answer (score 1):

This Q&A is old, but I have just noticed the same behaviour with a `UIWebView` (with input fields) presented modally and found a workaround to preserve

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {    
    return YES; 
}
```

If this method is removed or `return NO`, the keyboard shows up correctly (as pointed out by DotSlashSlash), but the same result is obtained putting

```
[self resignFirstResponder];
```

just before

```
[self presentModalViewController:aViewController animated:animated];
```